# Test execution failed using selenium - robot

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

```
Guys I need help to run the robot using Selenium. When trying to run the browser it opens very quickly and closes, I can't access the amazon website. I have already updated the chromedriver to the compatible version of my browser but I still get the InvalidArgumentException message: Message: invalid argument showing the browser screen in white.
```

```
obs: I've already reinstalled the drivers for the versions I have of firefox and chrome but I still can't run.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qlsq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMoNg.png)

I tried to run the robot and I couldn't because the error message is displayed

InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the browser and web-url arguments?
like:
open browser    https://www.amazon.com/    chrome

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).